# Highcharts - How to hide series name and Y value in tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, tooltip

Hovering over a series in [Highchart graph](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) displays a popup with series name and Y value, in the example: 'Tokyo 9.5ºC'. I would like to display my own, custom text on hover - I can do that by modifying each point's name. At the same time I would like to hide the default series name and Y value. I've searched the doc but haven't found anything suitable. Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll have to specify a tooltip formatter yourself (see [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter)):

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return 'The value for <b>'+ this.x +
           '</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b>';
  }
},
```

there you can just show the x-values if you like or your custom text.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the DEMO and created a new [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/2p32639L/) here

To customize the text displayed in the [`tooltip`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip), you should use it like:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },
........
.....
....

    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<strong>X value: </strong>'+ this.x;
      }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to format the second line of the tool tip, but leave the x-axis label name alone you can use point format instead of formatter.

```
tooltip: {
     pointFormat: 'The value is point.y'
},
```